# When loading data from text file, how to use Text Import Wizard instead of Power Query?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I go to Data -> From text I see this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX3Qn.png]

and it used to look like this

[image: http://www.jkp-ads.com/images/importtext06.gif]

Is it possible to go back to the old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Excel defaults to the Get&Transform tools for Text files, you are using one of the latest versions of Office 365. In these versions, there are settings in File > Options > Data, where you can tick which legacy data import wizards you want to show.

[image]

When any of these wizards are ticked, they will show up under Data > Get Data > Legacy Wizards.

[image]